# GitLab like program for easier collaborative video production

Tags: software-recommendation, post-production, production, storage

As a CIO in a small video production bussiness I'm making my team work more efficent using various tools.

Recently I noticed that the file versioning on a local NAS server is still confusing for some of CGI dept guys and there are situations when they asks me where should they put 'those' files.

I really don't want to keep answering such questions so I'm looking for a program like GitHub / GitLab which will force video editing workers to just pull all the project revelant data (like hunderds GiGs of video clips, images, sounds and so on) and when it's ready - push every new or changed file intro adequate folder in NAS server structure (typically just ten's of MB's like new Premiere Pro project files).

I've tested programs like FreeFileSync and DirSync Pro, they may do the work, but I don't want to make everyone learn using a new program, so a Windows context menu entry such as "Pull a new project..." or "Push changes of current project" is a must! And because we are keeping every raw footage files, the sync must be one-way only.

Do you know such simple programs which will do the job?

Marty

Comment: Version control for binary files, especially large video files, is hard. The best workflow a lock-merge-unlock workflow, which is complicated for non-technical end users. [Sony Ci](https://www.sonymcs.com/) might meet your needs. Otherwise you are going to need to look at the various MAM solutions, which would probably need significant customization for your environment. Others might have different suggestions, but it might depend on your environment. What NLE and OS are your editors using?

Answer (score 1):

Try Resilio Sync it will push or pull or both files from a server, pc etc and keep them all updated.